# Can you find Measures in OLAPQueryLog?

Tags: ssas, olap

Is it possible to find what Measures are used by looking at the OLAPQueryLog?

It's easy enough to get the attributes and dimensions from the DataSet column. However, I can't see any information about the measures (and calculated measures) that are used.

The main think I need to do I see how often new measures are used after we release them.

Turning on full event logging would be overkill for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The SSAS DMVs can be used to track measure usage and statistics.  These can be queried from any tool that can be used to submit DAX or MDX queries.  For example, by connecting to SSAS through SSMS and opening a new query editor window (click on the cube name and press `CTRL + N`).  The following objects can be queried just as a table in SQL would be.  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee301466(v=sql.105).aspx) contains more details on the specifics of what each column means.  The last two DMVs (`DISCOVER_COMMANDS` and `DISCOVER_SESSIONS`) include details about what measures were used in the `COMMAND_TEXT` and `SESSION_LAST_COMMAND` columns, respectively.

**Reads, Writes, Number of Times Object Hit in Cache and Similar Stats:**

```
$SYSTEM.DISCOVER_OBJECT_ACTIVITY
```

**Memory Usage:**

```
$SYSTEM.DISCOVER_OBJECT_MEMORY_USAGE
```

**Measure Details:**

```
$SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES
```

**Track Submitted Commands:**

```
$SYSTEM.DISCOVER_COMMANDS
```

**Monitor Sessions:**

```
$SYSTEM.DISCOVER_SESSIONS
```